# How to get document list by last version, where version is a field?

Tags: mongodb

I'm new on MongoDB, on my project i'm saving any change on specific document creating a new document with changes and a version field increased.

Example:

```
{_id:"X", number : "1", firstname : "John", lastname : "Sand", version : "1"}
{_id:"Y", number : "1", firstname : "John", lastname : "Snow", version : "2"}
{_id:"Z", number : "2", firstname : "Cersei", lastname : "Lannister", version: "1"}
```

When I have to show data i should get the last version of document distincted by field "number"

the result expected is:

```
{_id:"Y", number : "1", firstname : "John", lastname : "Snow", version : "2"}
{_id:"Z", number : "2", firstname : "Cersei", lastname : "Lannister", version: "1"}
```

Is there a method to do this with one query? 
I'm looking for aggregation but the subject is very dispersive.

Answer (score 2):

If the `number` element is an entity identifier, then you can use the aggregation.

At first, you need to [sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort) documents by the `version` value.

Then you need to [group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) documents by the `number` value and take values of the [first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first) document from the group.

And finally, you need to format the data output.

Example:

```
db.getCollection('collection_name').aggregate([
    {
        $sort: {'version': -1}
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$number",
            original_id: {$first: "$_id"},
            firstname: {$first: "$firstname"},
            lastname: {$first: "$lastname"},
            version: {$first: "$version"},
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: "$original_id",
            number: "$_id",
            firstname: 1,
            lastname: 1,
            version: 1
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Good! Thank you!